# Can't use filebeat [beat][timezone] with logstash date filter plugin?

Tags: timezone, logstash, filebeat

I'm sending a log file to logstash using filebeat that does not encode timezone in the timestamp. For months I've been seeding the logstash date filter plugin with the [beat][timezone] added using the filebeat processor "add_locale" abbreviation format. I have servers in several timezones around the world and when the time changed on the east coast of the US today from EST to EDT logstash started having timezone parse errors with the new timezone value because filebeat sent EDT, which is not a valid canonical ID timezone for logstash (http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html). I have the same issue with CEST and CET.

Is it possible that filebeat and logstash use different timezone filed formats?

FILEBEAT

```
processors:
- add_locale:
    format: abbreviation
```

LOGSTASH

```
date {
    locale => "en"
    match => ["corp.log.entryTimestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
    timezone => "%{[beat][timezone]}"
    tag_on_failure => ["timestamp_parse_failed"]
    target =>  "@timestamp"
}
```

It looks like filebeat just returns whatever [go](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Zone) returns.

Has anyone found a workaround for this?

thanks!

Peter

Answer (score 0):

It's generally not a good idea to try to parse time zone abbreviations.  Besides the cases you pointed out, there are just too many ambiguities.

Consider "CST".  Is that Central Standard Time (US), Central Standard Time (Australia), China Standard Time, Cuba Standard Time, something else?

Only a very few abbreviations are also valid IANA time zone identifiers. Other than UTC, they are generally discouraged.  They only exist for backwards compatibility reasons around a few edge cases.

In the case of timestamps in log files, abbreviations are pretty much useless, and you probably don't need a full time zone identifier like `America/New_York`.  It would suffice to have the offset from UTC that was in effect at the time recorded, such as `-05:00` (during EST) or `-04:00` (during EDT)

Indeed, according to the [filebeat docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/add-locale.html), the default format is `offset`.  I'd stick with that.

Comment: Note, I don't use these particular technologies myself, so I can only answer from a time zone best practices perspective.  It's entirely possible that *some* abbreviations are known to be common between the two worlds, but they would be nonstandard.

Comment: I hear what you're saying, however, logstash auto-corrects to UTC if the timezone isn't included in the timestamp (out of my control), the date filter doesn't accept an offset and I don't see any date calculation functions in logstash.  I'm open to other ways of doing this but it looks like I need to create my own mapping for now or hard code all of them which will break when daylight savings ends.

Comment: [The docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html#plugins-filters-date-match) show a `ZZ` token you can use in the `match` format.  Does that work?

Comment: Thanks I did try that but my problem is I have no control of the application that is outputting the timestamp in the application log, the original entry doesn't have the ZZ and I can't find a way to make the adjustment with filebeat or with logstash.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what else to suggest.  Perhaps someone else will be able to offer more.